# How do I Populate Multi Select drop dwon using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here I am listing all cars.customers want to compare car so they will select from this drop down. A person can select multiple cars. At the first time he is selecting 'Audi' and Saab' I will store it into data base next if he came I need to populate Saab and audi  as select how I can do this using php

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

Here is my code

```
<select  id="cars" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="cars[]">
    <?PHP 

        if($carslist->num_rows() >0)
        {
             foreach($carslist->result_array() as $entry):  

              ?> <option value="<?php echo($entry['ID']); ?>" ><?php echo($entry['car_name']); ?></option> 
              <?php 

              endforeach;
        }
          ?>    
</select>
```

Following code I tried $resources contain select cars

```
<select  id="cars" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="cars[]">
    <?PHP 

        if($carslist->num_rows() >0)
        {
             foreach($carslist->result_array() as $entry):  
                 if($resources->num_rows() >0)
                 { 

                     foreach($resources->result_array() as $car): 

                       if($entry['ID'] == $employee['car_id'])
                        {
                           $select = 'selected="selected"';                    

                        }
                       else
                        {
                           $select = '';                       

                        }   

                 endforeach;    
                 }                        
              ?> <option value="<?php echo($entry['ID']); ?>" <?php echo $select;?>  ><?php echo($entry['car_name']); ?></option> 
              <?php 

              endforeach;
        }
?>  
    </select>
```

but it showing error

Comment: Your doing it wrong buddy, you dont put logic in views. do that in models/controllers. Only the loop will be there in your view.

Comment: In models I fetch the details from database.I dont think so its needed.

Comment: My logic is wrong. Here only the mistake the foreach loop only the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try something like this, and see if it works:

Here is the **controller**:

```
<?php
    function something(){
        $data               = array();
        $data['cars']       = $this->some_model->some_function_to_return_cars_array();
        $data['selected']   = $some_array_of_selected_cars();
        $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
    }
?>
```

And this is the **view**:

```
<select  id="cars" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="cars[]">
    <option value="">Select:</option>
    <?php
        foreach( $cars as $key => $val ){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $val['some_id'] ?>" 
        <?php
            if( in_array( $val['some_id'], $selected ) ) echo ' selected';
        ?>

        ><?php echo $val['some_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you I forgot about in_array function thank you once again